# Svg is overflowing container height which is set to h-full/100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I am using react, d3js and zoom-pan-pinch. Below is a simplified version of my code (it replicates the exact same problem I'm having with the full code).

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  
<html>
<body>
<div id="root">
       <div id="main" class="bg-zinc-100 h-screen w-screen px-8 pb-4 flex flex-col">
          <div class="w-full flex flex-row h-12 justify-between items-center py-8">
             <img src="" class="h-6" alt="img here">text
             <div class="pl-2 w-20 h-10 rounded-full bg-white flex flex-row justify-around items-center">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" class="w-5 h-6">
                   <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5"></path>
                </svg>
                <img class="inline-block h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491528323818-fdd1faba62cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80" alt="avatar">
             </div>
          </div>
          <div id="workspace" class="flex flex-row gap-6 h-full">
             <svg viewBox="0 0 105 93" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-full w-full" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path d="M66,0h39v93zM38,0h-38v93zM52,35l25,58h-16l-8-18h-18z" fill="#ED1C24"></path>
             </svg>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I must preserve the screen size, overflow is not allowed. The thing is, eveything keeps inside the screen size, but when I add an SVG it keeps overflowing. I added h-full, w-full and preserveAspectRatio="none" (and tried another to keep it as a square) following other solutions I found (unsuccesfull in this case).

Is there a way (css/js) to keep that svg just inside the div? Filling 100% of its parent div, and without overflowing. And if so, is there a way to keep the original aspectRatio taking into account the changing width and size? I appreciate any help... Making that thing responsive is being a big headache

Edit:

[image]

I filled the bg with a slightly darker color, as you can see the svg is outside 100vh and 100vw.

Comment: Ok! Just added the snippet in last edit. Thanks

Comment: Not sure how you can preserve a square aspect ratio AND have it match the height AND width at the same time since the width is always likely to be the largest dimension. If you have a square matching the remaining height it won't be wide enough and if you match the width it will overflow the height.